# React.js: useEffect with window resize event listener not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using this code to listen for resize events in a function component and rerender the component when the window is resized. The problem is, nothing ever gets printed out for either event listener, so I think I have a misunderstanding of how I'm using useEffect here.

```
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      console.log(dimensions.width);
      setDimensions({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
      window.addEventListener("load", handleResize, false);
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
    };
  });
```

Comment: For one, your `window.addEventListener` calls are _inside_ `handleResize`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  });
console.log(dimensions);
const handleResize = () => {
    setDimensions({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    });
  }
React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize, false);
}, []);
```

Comment: This is clean simple, thanks!. Why the listener must be inside the useEffect hook? Why it cant just be added once?

Comment: @nivalderramas because it is in useEffect, with an empty dependency array, it does just get added once.

Answer (score 36):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// Usage
function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div>
      {size.width}px / {size.height}px
    </div>
  );
}
// Hook
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
  return windowSize;
}
```

[SOURCE](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/)

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, especially since it handles the cleanup of the eventlistener.

Comment: Awesome solution. Works for next.js too, tested.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the event listener on "resize" was not sufficient to populate the window dimensions in the initial load of the page. The following worked for me.

```js
function getWindowDimensions() {
  const {innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height} = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}

function useWindowDimensions() {
  const defaultDim = {width: null, height: null}
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(defaultDim);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions()) // Necessary to make sure dimensions are set upon initial load

    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```